# Connect django project with mongodb

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongodb

I am not getting any migrations for `mongodb`(no changes made when i am done with python `manage.py` migrate commmand) while i am using `djongo` in `settings.py` file of my django project.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'student_db', #database_name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be needing `#database_name` in settings.py. Make the below changes 
`DATABASES = { 'default': { 'ENGINE': 'djongo', 'NAME': 'student_db'} }`

Comment: I have used the same as you write in comment but i have not run the below command:-
pip install djongo

that's why i was facing the issue.

Comment: Cool, glad you could resolve the issue @HimanshuKumarRajput. :-)